# cloudbees clickstart for spring mvc hibernate application

Tags: cloudbees

I have spring mvc hibernate application and after deploying it on tomcat 7 clickstart on cloudbees I am getting database connection error.App address is http://tirebook.tireb10.cloudbees.net What is the right clickstart for my app?

Comment: Perhaps posting exact error message gives some clues. The more information you supply the higher chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your application with your database. For a Spring app you can add this to your datasource.xml conf file in order to use JNDI.

```
<!-- JNDI DataSource for JEE environments -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mydb" resource-ref="true"/>
```

Then, you can auto-insert the datasource into the container through the CloudBees SDK.

```
bees app:bind -a MYAPP -db MYDB -as mydb
```

You will need to redeploy your app after this.

```
bees app:deploy -a MYAPP -t tomcat7 app.war
```

Comment: Hi felix I have already bind my app and configured jndi resource.To get the error message you can click http://tirebook.tireb10.cloudbees.net and then login.

Comment: After login with a test account, I cannot see any error message. Please, edit your question and provide the stacktrace.